# How can I insert user's IP_Address to database dynamically after logged-in with the help of ID(Foreign Key)?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax

I have a store procedures for user login which I am calling in my Data Repository code. And now I want that, when user logged-in, the IP Address and Date time of the user's system should get saved in a table with the help of the ID which is a reference from another table(Foreign Key). I need to save the IP Address in 192.167.1.78 format.

This is my stored procedure to save IP Address and Date Time with the help of user's ID :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Sp_LoginIpAddress]    
(
@LoginDate datetime,
@IpAddress varchar(50)
)
as
begin

DECLARE @EmpId INT
select EmpId from EmpRegister

if not exists(select * from LoginDetails where EmpId=@EmpId)
begin

insert into LoginDetails( LoginDate , IpAddress)
values ( @LoginDate , @IpAddress)

set @EmpId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

select cast(@EmpId as int)  
end
else
begin
select cast(0 as int)
end
end
```

I have a 4 columns in my [LoginDetails] table. They are LoginId, EmpId , LoginDate, IpAddress.

Here EmpId is a foreign key Contraint.

**Here is my controller code:**

```
  public ActionResult GetIP()
        {
            GetIPAddress();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveIpAddress(LoginDetail log)
        {


            ActionResult response = null;

            try
            {
                int intResult = 0;

                log.LoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                string IP = GetIPAddress().ToString();
                log.IpAddress = IP;
                intResult = _registrationrepository.SaveIpAddress(log);

                if (intResult >= 1) //inserted successfully
                {

                    response = Json(new { result = "Success" });
                }
                else if (intResult == -1)
                {

                    response = Json(new { result = "Exists", url = Url.Action("Emp", "VerifyOTP") });
                }
                else if (intResult == 0) //Duplicate record rule violation
                {

                    response = Json(new { result = "InsertFail" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else //On Error
                {
                    response = Json(new { result = "Error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return response;

        }



        private string GetIPAddress()
        {

            string strHostName = "";
            strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

            IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

            string ipaddress = Convert.ToString(ipEntry.AddressList[2]);
            ViewBag.IPAddress = ipaddress;
            return ipaddress.ToString();


        }
```

**Here is my DataRepository and IDataRepository:**

**DataRepository:**

```
 public int SaveIpAddress(LoginDetail log)
        {
            int finalResult = 0;

            try
            {
                ObjectResult<int?> CRId = objEntities.Sp_LoginIPAddress(
                                                                      log.LoginId,
                                                                      log.LoginDate,
                                                                      log.IpAddress                                                                                                                                       
                                                                       );
                var result = CRId.FirstOrDefault<int?>();

                if (result.HasValue)
                {

                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        //on Success
                        finalResult = result.Value;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // on failure 
                    finalResult = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return finalResult;

        }
```

**IDataRepository:**

```
    public interface IRegistrationRepository 
    {
      int SaveIpAddress(LoginDetail log);
    }
```

So, I expect the output like when user logged-in the IpAddress and DateTime should get saved in a LoginDetail tables directly through the backend functionality.

Comment: You do not appear, in your controller, to call `SaveIpAddress`. Also why would the client call the `GetIP` action? You would be better off doing this in a filter.

Comment: @Richard I called `SaveIpAddress` in a script. Can you please elaborate that how it would be done in filter?

Comment: "in a script": what script? (And filters is too big a topic for one answer: there is a lot of documentation including introductions on the web, but be careful to avoid ASP.NET vs ASP.NET Core confusion.

Comment: Slight detour...http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix